# PySpark: How to add columns for the next and previous event in a sorted database?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

Let's say I've got dataset like this one:

```
  +----------+------------+----------+ -----------+
  |userId     |event      |timestamp | session_id |
  +----------+------------+----------+ -----------+
  |U1        |A           |1         | 11         |
  |U1        |B           |2         | 11         |
  |U1        |C           |5         | 11         |
  |U1        |C           |7         | 12         |
  |U2        |A           |8         | 13         |
  |U2        |D           |20        | 13         |
  |U3        |B           |23        | 14         |
  +----------+------------+----------+------------+
```

The dataset is sorted based on the session_id and the timestamp. I would like to add a column called "next_event" where it should be placed the next event in the session (so in this database the event in the row below) if it exists. If there is no next event in the session, it should put "NA" or something similar.

Similarly, I would like to add a column called "prev_event" where it should be placed the previous event in the session (so in this database the event in the row above) if it exists. If there is no previous event in the session, it should put "NA" or something similar.

This is optional, but it would be very helpful if I could also add a column called "uniq_id" from the beginning of the dataset until the end that would be numbered from 0 to n-1 or from 1 to n. And another column "next_id" similar to "next_event" but that instead of the next_event specifies the next uniq_id. This isn't necessary, but I think it might help me later on.

```
   +----------+------------+----------+ -----------+------------+------------+---------+---------+
  |userId    |event      |timestamp | session_id | next_event  | prev_event | uniq_id | next_id |
  +----------+------------+----------+ -----------+-------------+------------+---------+---------+
  |U1        |A           |1         | 11         |   B         |   NA       |  1      | 2       |
  |U1        |B           |2         | 11         |   C         |   A        |  2      | 3       |
  |U1        |C           |5         | 11         |   NA        |   B        |  3      | NA      |
  |U1        |C           |7         | 12         |   NA        |   NA       |  4      | NA      |
  |U2        |A           |8         | 13         |   D         |   NA       |  5      | 6       |
  |U2        |D           |20        | 13         |   NA        |   A        |  6      | NA      |
  |U3        |B           |23        | 14         |   NA        |   NA       |  7      | NA      |
  +----------+------------+----------+------------+-------------+------------+---------+---------+
```

I would like this to be done in PySpark.
Any sort of help or guidance is very appreciated! Thanks

Edit: I think I could use lag and lead with a Window for this, but I'm not exactly sure how

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using lead and lag. Example is in Scala since I have it set up to make some code that compiles and runs. Concepts are exactly the same, just the syntax is different.

Idea being that the window defines the partition and sorting. Then use lead and lag to pull the values from other rows into the current one relative to the window's sorting. By default if nothing can be found it returns null.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

case class Event(userId: String, event: String, timestamp: Long, session_id: Long)

val spark = SparkSession.builder
  .master("local")
  .appName("Simple Application").getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._

val eventDS = Seq(
  Event("U1", "A", 1, 11),
  Event("U1", "B", 2, 11),
  Event("U1", "C", 5, 11),
  Event("U1", "C", 7, 12),
  Event("U2", "A", 8, 13),
  Event("U3", "D", 20, 13),
  Event("U3", "B", 23, 14)
).toDS()

val timestampBySessionWindow = Window.partitionBy($"session_id").orderBy($"timestamp")

eventDS
  .withColumn("next_event", lead("event", 1).over(timestampBySessionWindow))
  .withColumn("prev_event ", lag("event", 1).over(timestampBySessionWindow))
  .show()
```

This results in.

```
+------+-----+---------+----------+----------+-----------+
|userId|event|timestamp|session_id|next_event|prev_event |
+------+-----+---------+----------+----------+-----------+
|    U1|    C|        7|        12|      null|       null|
|    U1|    A|        1|        11|         B|       null|
|    U1|    B|        2|        11|         C|          A|
|    U1|    C|        5|        11|      null|          B|
|    U2|    A|        8|        13|         D|       null|
|    U3|    D|       20|        13|      null|          A|
|    U3|    B|       23|        14|      null|       null|
+------+-----+---------+----------+----------+-----------+
```

If you want a unique id add a monotonically_increasing_id. This is more performant than doing it by row number since monotonically_increasing_id doesn't require a shuffle while by row number requires moving all of the data into a single executor.

```
df.withColumn("uniq_id", monotonically_increasing_id())
```